# Google Calendar API: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am creating a fairly simple Java client that connects to my account and gets all the events. Here I am getting an exception saying :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.Maps
```

Could anyone tell me which JAR am I missing and moreover where to download it from?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), now known as [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by download the jar file guava-r07.jar.
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/detail?name=guava-r07.zip
Try it.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who use Maven, here's the dependency entry for guava:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Credit where credit is due: the above is from http://mavenrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/19.0

Comment: Thanks Christian ! Fortunately, we also moved to maven (much after I asked this question though)

Comment: Yeah, I realize that I'm a little late to this party. Hopefully, someone will benefit from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try importing google-collect-1.0-rc1.jar?
It can be found at (in the source tree) :
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/deps

Thanks,
Renu

Answer (score 0):

I also solved this problem by including guava dependency. Guava is superset of the old Google Collections Library. Here is the link: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/21.0 
Include this dependency in your build.sbt

Comment: While this may answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the 
essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Have made the changes @TomAranda